# access to clients width domain name instead of IP address

Tags: dns, dhcp

I have a local network (no internet) and I want to access to clients with domain name instead of IP address.
Is that possible?
The router is ASUS RT-N12+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If clients can access the app by ip address, all you need to do is assign this ip address to a host name to be able to access the service by that host name.

You can either do this by creating a host in a domain you have DNS control over, or you can use a service like dyndns to get a sub-domain you can allocate host names in.

If the service is behind a NAT firewall/router (on unregistered IPs, e.g 192.168.*.*), and the clients are **external**, then you would need to be able to set up port-forwarding on the firewall/router. For that RTFM.